# how to loop through json data based on single column value using angularjs in mvc

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I need to display data from two tables which are associated with foreign key
    using angularjs in mvc. I am able repeat question but my requirement is display question with 4 options i couldnt get the solution for this, am new to angularjs,I will be thankful if anyone  can help  me

```
> Controller code :

  public JsonResult displayQuestion()
        {

            var result = from q in Db.questions
                         join a in Db.answers on q.Qid equals a.questionID
                         select new { q.QText, q.Qid, a.answer1 };
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

> angular view code:

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module("QuestionDisplayModule", [])
        .controller("QuestionDisplayController", function ($scope,$http,$log) {
            $http.get("displayQuestion").then(function(response)
            {
                $log.info(response);
                $scope.questionsData = response.data;
            })
        })
    </script>
    <title>dispaly</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="QuestionDisplayModule">
    <div ng-controller="QuestionDisplayController">
        <div ng-repeat="q in questionsData">
            <h6>{{q.QText}}</h6>
            <p><input type="radio" name="answers" ng-repeat = "a in q.answer1" />{{a.answer1}}</p>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

> json data result:

```
[
    {"QText":"result of 2+2","Qid":2,"answer1":"2"},
    {"QText":"result of 2+2","Qid":2,"answer1":"4"},
    {"QText":"result of 2+2","Qid":2,"answer1":"6"},
    {"QText":"result of 2+2","Qid":2,"answer1":"8"}
]
```

> view result: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WldUp.png)

Comment: show the json you were getting by the `get` request

Comment: i have added just check it @PraveshKhatri

Comment: why are you iterating in `answers`. just remove `ng-repeat = "a in q.answer1"` and in your `{{}}` use `{{q.answer1}}`

Comment: if i write {{q.answer1}}  question  is repeat  4 times, but i need to dispaly  one question  with 4 options @PraveshKhatri

Comment: did you get my concept  @PraveshKhatri

Comment: Then you have a wrong or unformatted json. I think the json must be like `{"QText":"result of 2+2","Qid":2,"answer1":[{"option1":"2"},{"option1":"4"},{"option1":"6"},{"option1":"8"}]}`. Now the above code you have written will work

Comment: yes but how i will get that formatted data using query..thats what am thinking,do u know that @PraveshKhatri